# How to find the version of library from Gradle Dependency? Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

## Question:

How do I find the version of libraries that are being used when my Gradle file mentions a dependency using the '+' operator in the version number of the dependency?

### Context

My `build.gradle` under app module reads like so:

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.+'
}
```

What is the version of the play-services library that is being used here?

Comment: Do you want to determine this programmatically in your build.gradle script?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice No just wanted to know for reference.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I'd love to know how to do this programmatically.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

## Look under `.idea` folder of your project

In the `Project Pane` on the left, browse to `.idea/libraries`

All the library dependencies that your project has have been mentioned, with each one getting its own xml file. You can see the version number included in the xml file title. The xml itself has the library file path.

[image: snapshot of .idea/libraries]

## (OR) Use Gradle's built in task to get dependencies

See steps here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25236208/1311745

Comment: Why the downvote without a comment? It's simple and just works! No Gradle Command wu-foo!

Comment: I tried this method and found no help to my problem. those xml file titles are just the same as the library file names. And library file I am using does not have its version number in the file name

Comment: this doesn't show you the dependency tree that would be needed to solve dependency conflicts

Comment: I'll add a link to Gradle answer, did the other answer help? I've not checked it myself and am not sure if the output that provides the dependency tree

Comment: @kazuar, but the question isn't asking about solving dependency conflicts. Just seeing the version, which this does.

Answer (score 34):

You can use gradles' build-in 'dependencyInsight' task to query the resolved version of your dependency:

```
gradle dependencyInsight --configuration compile --dependency com.google.android.gms:play-services
```

If you want to get an overview for all your dependencies in one go, you can do

```
gradle dependencies
```

If you use the gradle wrapper you must use `./gradlew` instead of `gradle`

Comment: a) can I do this for all dependencies at a go? b) If I'm using the gradle wrapper, how can I make this work? also gradle is not on system PATH.

Comment: yes you can do this in one go. I've updated my question with according example

Comment: @ReneGroeschke, I'm getting this error * What went wrong:
Configuration with name 'compile' not found.
any Idea, thanks.

Comment: @Hesam don't forget the your sub project prefix, dependencyInsight --configuration compile --dependency com.google.android.gms:play-services doesn't work but lib:dependencyInsight --configuration compile --dependency com.google.android.gms:play-services works (lib is my sub project name)

Comment: @cn123h this also does not work anymore, even by specifying the project folder. The only thing working presently is `./gradlew dependencies`, and then go through the tree structure to figure out which version it is. Unless someone knows how the new syntax is.

Comment: Can I do this in the Terminal of Android Studio? Shouldn't it have the executable preloaded onto the path? Where's it located?

Answer (score 8):

**Android Gradle Dependency library version**

Android Studio 3.1.4

You are able to use `Project` view

[image]

Comment: I have two different versions here. How to know which one is used?

Answer (score 2):

In Android Studio, in the build.graddle app, select the version and press ALT + ENTER, then select "Replace with specifyc version"