# Android: How to use couch db as local storage with android application?

Tags: android, couchdb, database, nosql

I am developing an android app in which i need to store data into couch db.anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Couchbase Mobile which is CouchDB for mobile and tablet devices. Here is the [link](http://developer.couchbase.com/mobile/).

Comment: tnx i will try it out and will let you know

Comment: yep it's working now but when we give dependency in build.gradle file by default which version is downloaded of couchDB 1)Community Edition or 2)Enterprise Edition?

Comment: From this SO post http://stackoverflow.com/a/25233561/2244476, you can know the version of the library being used. Could you please check if you can get to know the edition from this?